# JavaScript - Filter two arrays with similar objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I'm trying to compare results from two different arrays containing similar strings;

**Array1:**

```
A350.1 - 2h 46 m
A210.2 - 3h 46 m
```

**Array2:**

```
A450.3 - 8h 0 m
A440.5 - 13h 0 m
A450.1 - 4h 0 m
A350.1 - 1h 45 m
A320.7 - 3h 45 m
```

So I would need to filter out `A350.1 - 2h 46 m` from **Array1** since there's a similar object `A350.1 - 1h 45 m` in **Array2**

The results should look like this from the filtered array, only removing the object which has the identical name (in this example `A350.1`):

```
A210.2 - 3h 46 m
```

Any way I could do this effectively and push the results in a new filtered array?

Comment: Is it a string array? `["A350.1 - 2h 46 m", "A210.2 - 3h 46 m"]`?  or arrays with `objects`? Can you write down the exact array here in Javascript?

Comment: @sabithpocker I'm pushing these objects to an empty array (Array1, Array2) from a JSON response.

Comment: So if there is a conflict, item from `array2` is taken always? Can you explain what you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```js
var arr1 = ["A350.1 - 2h 46 m", "A210.2 - 3h 46 m"]
var arr2 = ["A450.3 - 8h 0 m",
  "A440.5 - 13h 0 m",
  "A450.1 - 4h 0 m",
  "A350.1 - 1h 45 m",
  "A320.7 - 3h 45 m"
]
var firstPart = [];
arr1.forEach(function(obj1) {
  firstPart.push(obj1.substring(0, obj1.indexOf('-')))
});
arr2.forEach(function(obj2) {
  var i = firstPart.indexOf(obj2.substring(0, obj2.indexOf('-')));
  if (i !== -1)
    arr1.splice(i, 1);
});
console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a loop that compare each values of Array1 against each values of Array2 and split your string like so `array1[i].split("-");` to only compare the first part of your string

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your lookup array by splitting off the interesting bit

```
var arr2_prepared = arr2.map(x => x.split(' - ')[0]);
```

Then filter out the elements from the data array that do not have the first part of their strings in the lookup array

```
var result = arr1.filter(x => arr2_prepared.indexOf(x.split(' - ')[0]) === -1);
```